# Regras de negócios devem ficar na Entity na obordagem DDD

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, ddd

Seguindo a metodologia DDD (Domain Driven Develop), minha duvida é se a classe entity deve receber alguma regra de negócio.

Imagine a situação:
Temos um CarFactory responspável por contruir diferentes tipos de carros, onde instância classe especificas de carros (entities)...
Cada entity deve ter dentro de si regras para receber valores espcificos, como por exemplo cor, números de porta e etc... ?

1-Como deve ser organizado as regras de negócio? Qual camada q a regra de negócios se encontra?
2-Enitity devem ter validadores de valores para suas propriedades?
Entity deve pode receber um array com valores para a própria entity "set" valores para suas propriedades ou pode haver uma classe q espcifica valores que dever ser passados para a entity?

Answer (score 1):

Não,

As `Entity` são classes de objetos e precisam ter uma identidade, ou seja, algo que identifica que aquela `entity` é única. Como por exemplo o `id` ou `uuid`. Nas `entities` apenas irão os atributos e os métodos acessadores quando necessários.

Quando desenvolvo utilizando a metodologia DDD (Domain Driven Development), na minha opinião, as classes de serviços são as responsáveis pelas regras de negócio.

Mas outro ponto que deve levar em consideração são as *Factories* e *Aggregates*, onde cada um tem sua responsabilidade para que apenas as regras de negócios sejam colocadas nas classes de serviços.

Referências

1. [DDD](http://www.agileandart.com/2010/07/16/ddd-introducao-a-domain-driven-design/)
2. [DDD E-book](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly)
3. [Projeto Básico DDD no Git](https://github.com/rdehnhardt/ddd-example)

Answer (score 0):

Para responder a sua pergunta é necessário dividí-la em partes:

> Seguindo a metodologia DDD (Domain Driven Develop), minha duvida é se
>   a classe entity deve receber alguma regra de negócio.

Sim, quando a regra de negócio (no DDD é chamada de lógica do domínio) "couber" dentro da entidade (exemplos a seguir).

> Imagine a situação: Temos um CarFactory responspável por contruir
>   diferentes tipos de carros, onde instância classe especificas de
>   carros (entities)... Cada entity deve ter dentro de si regras para
>   receber valores espcificos, como por exemplo cor, números de porta e
>   etc... ?

Sim. A cor, quantidade de portas, marca, motor, dentre outros, são propriedades do carro, logo, a entidade carro é quem deve ser responsável por carregar tais propriedades.

Entretanto, é necessário observar que, dependendo do Domínio, algumas destas propriedades podem ter um ciclo de vida completamente independente. Como, por exemplo, em um software para retíficas de motores, onde o motor terá um papel mais importante do que o próprio carro. Logo, a entidade Carro terá uma propriedade Motor que, diferentemente das propriedades cor e número de portas, será uma nova entidade com seu próprio ciclo de vida.

> 1-Como deve ser organizado as regras de negócio? Qual camada q a regra
>   de negócios se encontra?

Respondido acima. Mas para deixar claro: a regra básica é pensar qual classe deve ter a responsabilidade de ter e/ou fazer algo. No exemplo do carro, é ele quem deve saber a sua cor, número de portas e tipo de motor. Mas não é o carro quem deve fabricar outros carros, por isso a existência de uma factory.

> 2-Enitity devem ter validadores de valores para suas propriedades?
>   Entity deve pode receber um array com valores para a própria entity
>   "set" valores para suas propriedades ou pode haver uma classe q
>   espcifica valores que dever ser passados para a entity?

Entidades podem e devem receber valores para suas propriedades, mas sempre é preciso pensar se a validação e outros comportamentos da propriedade em questão pertencem a entidade. Exemplo: No caso acima, da retífica de motores, a entidade Carro pode receber a entidade Motor, mas é o Motor, e não o Carro, quem deve validar se o número de cilindros do Motor está correto.

Por fim, caso a lógica de domínio não caiba na entidade, pode-se utilizar um dos outros blocos de construção do DDD: Objeto de Valor, Agregados, Eventos, Serviços, Repositório e Fábrica. Saiba mais em https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Building_blocks